# Given a presentation of a group, find its normalizer.

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $F$ and $H$ be two free groups, where $F = \langle a,b\rangle$ and $H = \langle aa,bb,aba,baab, babab\rangle$. Let $N(H)$ be the normalizer of $H$ in $F$.

How can I compute $N(H)/H$?

In general, given a presentation of a group, is there a way to find its normalizer?

Comment: In general, questions about finitely presented groups are typically undecidable, and the answer is no. There is an algorithm for calculating the normalizer of a finitely generated subgroup of a free group.But the specific problem you ask is rather easy. As a hint, $|F:H|$ is finite.